# SQL Total by category

Tags: php, mysql

My query gives to me the result for item (eqmt)

but i need the daily total of the items group by category (unit), I´m investigating inner join, but it´s out of my knowledge

This is the query with the total by equip and its work great.

```
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '1',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '2',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '3',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '4',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '5',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '6'
FROM hist_eqmtlist,hist_exproot,hist_statusevents
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.eqmt, hist_exproot.shiftdate, hist_eqmtlist.unit
ORDER BY hist_exproot.shiftdate,hist_statusevents.eqmt
```

And this is the same query but with the result by unit (category)

```
SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '1',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '2',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '3',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '4',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '5',
       sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end) as '6'
FROM hist_eqmtlist,hist_exproot,hist_statusevents
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid

GROUP BY hist_exproot.shiftdate, hist_eqmtlist.unit
ORDER BY hist_exproot.shiftdate
```

Why I need this?

Because I need to put this on my php and then put into a nested table

Comment: If you're using php then handle the display logic there. You can get rid of all this code. But yes, continue investigating inner join.